# Inserting datatable data to database using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, datatable

I am having a datatable and i want to insert data to database(SSMS) using Entity Framework. What is the Feasible solution for this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `DataTable` is raw rows and columns - Entity Framework works with .NET objects, which is fundamentally something else.

So you cannot just *easily* insert the rows and columns from a `DataTable` using EF.

You **either** need to iterate through your `DataTable` and build up objects from those rows & columns, stick those into a `List<YourObject>` and then persist those objects to the database using EF....

**or** you just skip EF and persist the "raw" `DataTable` to the database using raw ADO.NET (`SqlDataAdapter` or `SqlCommand` with an `INSERT` statement).

**Update:**

OK, so you want to convert your `DataTable` to objects. You need to have a class that represents your entity in the database - since you provided no information, I'm just going to call it `MyObject`

```
public class MyObject
{
   // define some properties
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   // whatever else this object has
}
```

You most likely already have such an object - an **entity** class - that exists in your database.

Then you need to define a method to convert the data table to a list of objects:

```
public List<MyObject> ConvertDataTable(DataTable tbl)
{
     List<MyObject> results = new List<MyObject>();

     // iterate over your data table
     foreach(DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
     {
         MyObject convertedObject = ConvertRowToMyObject(row);
         results.Add(convertedObject);
     }

     return results;
}
```

and now you need a last method to convert a single row to your object type:

```
public MyObject ConvertRowToMyObject(DataRow row)
{
     MyObject result = new MyObject();

     // assign the properties of MyObject from the DataRow
     result.ID = row.GetInt32(0);
     result.Name = row.GetString(1);
     // and so on .... convert the column values in the DataRow into the
     // properties of your object type

     return result;
}
```

Comment: I will choose this -> You either need to iterate through your DataTable and build up objects from those rows & columns, stick those into a List<YourObject> and then persist those objects to the database using EF...Can you please provide any sample code or link for this ?

Comment: I know this post is old but something that might be of value is:
https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/mapping-datatables-and-datarows-to-objects-in-csharp-and-net-using-reflection/

Comment: @Ken: thanks for the pointer - good blog, have seen interesting posts for various topics there already

Answer (score 2):

I found another way that is same but with less code and much easier i think. I thought I should share it here, might help others.

```
using (var productDB = new studentDBEntities()) //JFEntity object
      {
      for (int i = 0; i < DataExcelTable.Rows.Count; i++)
          {
                DataRow dr = DataExcelTable.Rows[i];
                productDB.Products.Add(new Product() 
                { //add data to class objects variable
                ProductName = dr["ProductNumber"].ToString(),
                ProductNumber=Convert.ToInt32 (dr["ProductNumber"]),
                Size=dr["size"].ToString(),
                Weight=Convert.ToInt32( dr["weight"]),
                Price=Convert.ToInt32(dr["price"]),
                SaleStatus=Convert.ToBoolean(dr["salestatus"])
                });
           } productDB.SaveChanges();
       }
```

Comment: Your method relies on a string value for each column name in the datatable (instead of an object property, for example).  If a column name changes, you'll have to update this code segment.

Comment: What a nice playground for SQL injections