# Inserting datatable into database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, datatable

I currently have a populated datatable from an excel workbook that I am trying to insert into my database.

Both the datatable as well as the table in my database have matching structures.

IE: Matching types, columns, and order of elements

I have a class that represents my entity within the database that would look something like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string GUID {get; set;}
}
```

From what I have gathered from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405153/inserting-datatable-data-to-database-using-entity-framework/22405349#22405349) I should be able to do the following to convert the data table I have created to a list of objects based off of MyObject.

```
public List<MyObject> ConvertDataTable(Datatable tbl)
{
    List<MyObject> results = new <MyObject>();

    foreach(DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
    {
        MyObject convertedObject = ConvertRowToMyObject(row)
        results.Add(convertedObject);
    }

    return results
}
```

The linked post also shows that it's necessary to convert single rows to the proper object data types, but it's that already inherited from MyObject?

```
public MyObject ConvertRowToMyObject(DataRow row)
{
    MyObject result = new MyObject();

    // Here the above post shows assigning properties of MyObject from the 
    // DataRow  
    result.ID = row.GetString(1);
    result.GUID = row.GetInt32(0);
    result.Name = row.GetString(1);

    // I haven't been able to get 'GetInt' or 'GetString' to work properly, 
    // but doesn't each property already have the correct type from
    // MyObject?

    return result;
}
```

Prior to inserting data is there a way to enumerate all items within a column such as -

```
foreach(DataColumn col in tbl.Columns)
```

But something that can iterate over,manipulate, and return data based off of values contained in a singular column?

Comment: why not do the manipulation in the ConvertRowToMyObject it self ? you can get the values of a column in data row by using row["column name"]

Comment: @Dheeraj So, in the third snippet what is the purpose of assigning types If I had already done so in the MyObject class?

I assumed it was as easy as that...what would row["Name"] return then? (what type)?

Comment: It would return a type object you can use row.Field<type>("fieldName"); instead this should work from .NET 4.0

Comment: @Dheeraj I attempted both ways:

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    
    dr["NAME"].ToString();

    // As well as

    dr.Field<myObject>("NAME");

Both of these throw the error of Column 'NAME' does not belong to table, but when I view my datatable it does in fact exist in the table,